# "Wrong assembly binding redirects" when running BenchmarkDotNet

Tags: c#, .net-core, assembly-binding-redirect, benchmarkdotnet

When running BenchmarkDotNet for a method in my project I get a few "Wrong assembly binding redirect" warning/error messages printed to screen. This got me a bit puzzled, as I thought assembly binding redirects is a .Net Framework concept, while my projects are .Net Core 3.0. Googling the warning/error message gave no result. Any tips to what these messages mean, and possibly how to fix the problem. I tried cleaning Nuget cache, restoring Nuget packages, cleaning and rebuilding the solution, but to no help.

```
// BeforeAnythingElse

// Benchmark Process Environment Information:
// Runtime=.NET Core 3.0.0 (CoreCLR 4.700.19.46205, CoreFX 4.700.19.46214), X64 RyuJIT
// GC=Concurrent Workstation
// Job: DefaultJob

OverheadJitting  1: 1 op, 308100.00 ns, 308.1000 us/op
// Wrong assembly binding redirects for System.Data.Common.resources, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.
// Wrong assembly binding redirects for System.Data.Common.resources, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.
// Wrong assembly binding redirects for System.Data.SqlClient.resources, Version=4.6.0.0, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.
// Wrong assembly binding redirects for System.Data.SqlClient.resources, Version=4.6.0.0, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.
// Wrong assembly binding redirects for System.Private.Xml.resources, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51.
// Wrong assembly binding redirects for System.Private.Xml.resources, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is that you can ignore this warning.

The long answer: for some reason VS sometimes generates invalid assembly binding redirects for Full .NET Framework projects that reference .NET Standard libraries. It was causing a lot of trouble to BenchmarkDotNet users in the past:

- https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet/issues/895,
- https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet/issues/667,
- https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet/issues/896,
- https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet/issues/942 .

I decided to implement an ugly workaround that searches for `.dll` file manually and loads it when .NET Framework fails to do so.

Of course, this applies only to Full .NET Framework. When I was porting BenchmarkDotNet to .NET Standard 2.0 I've forgotten that we don't need to do this for .NET Core. As the end result, you get this confusing warning.

I've sent a PR that fixes that: https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet/pull/1365 and this workaround will now be executed only for Full .NET Framework projects